# Json encode autocomplete source

Tags: php, jquery, json, cakephp-2.0, jquery-autocomplete

I usually have array like this

```
(int) 0 => abc,
(int) 1 => def,
(int) 2 => ghi
```

which if I use json_encode it will become

```
["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

this will perfectly be useful for jquery autocomplete

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($companyList); ?>;
    $("#CompanyName").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        delay: 10
    });
});
```

But now, I need more data and I take a look at jquery autocomplete example, the data has to look like this

```
var company = [
  {
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    name: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    address: "jquery_32x32.png",
    city: "xxxxx",
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    name: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    address: "jquery_32x32.png",
    city: "xxxxx",
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    name: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    address: "jquery_32x32.png",
    city: "xxxxx",
  }
];
```

how can I do json_encode (or any other way) to change a PHP array like this

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Company' => array(
            'id' => '19',
            'group_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Harts Harts',
            'address' => 'xxx NE xxxth Street',
            'city' => 'Shoreline',
            'state' => 'WA',
            'zip' => '98155',
            'country' => '',
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Company' => array(
            'id' => '21',
            'group_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Andy Robin',
            'address' => 'xxx xxxth Ave NE',
            'city' => 'Bellevue',
            'state' => 'WA',
            'zip' => '98004',
            'country' => '',
        )
    )
)
```

into something looks like the jquery autocomplete source, because if I directly use json_encode($company), it will become object and I can't use it for autocomplete.

This array will have around 2500ish data
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$return_arr = array();

$company_arr = array(
    (int) 0 =>  array(
        'id' => '19',
        'group_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Harts Harts',
        'address' => 'xxx NE xxxth Street',
        'city' => 'Shoreline',
        'state' => 'WA',
        'zip' => '98155',
        'country' => '',
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '21',
        'group_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Andy Robin',
        'address' => 'xxx xxxth Ave NE',
        'city' => 'Bellevue',
        'state' => 'WA',
        'zip' => '98004',
        'country' => '',
    )
);

foreach ($company_arr as &$company) {
    array_push($return_arr,$company);
}


echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Output:

```
[{"id":"19","group_id":"1","name":"Harts Harts","address":"xxx NE xxxth Street","city":"Shoreline","state":"WA","zip":"98155","country":""},{"id":"21","group_id":"1","name":"Andy Robin","address":"xxx xxxth Ave NE","city":"Bellevue","state":"WA","zip":"98004","country":""}]
```

http://codepad.org/dQ8r52Eq

Note: to use for jquery autocomplete, you will need to add a `value` or `label` field in your returned `json`. You currently don't have neither of those fields.

Comment: this way I feel like it will cause problem due to a huge amount of data (2500ish datas). It will be slow during page loading

Comment: @Hart I used the same code with US zip codes pulling several thousand at a time but if you have other things running on the page then maybe so.

Comment: @Harts if you are pulling from a database for the automcompete you could use my post example here: http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery parseJSON method to parse the json you get from PHP.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( 'json_string_here' );
```

Answer (score 0):

api jquery-ui: [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

After reading the api for autocomplete:

```
$companyList = array();
foreach($companies as $company){
    array_push( $companyList, $company["Company"]["name"]);
}
```

returns:

```
["Harts Harts","Andy Robin"]
```

autocomplete will work with this plan old array or a array of object properties `label` and `value` like so:

```
[{label:"Harts Harts",value:"Harts Harts"},{label:"Andy Robin",value:"Andy Robin"}]
```

If you have any more questions just ask.